# c# wpf - Binding to two ElementName

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, telerik

I want to bind the SelectedDate in RadCalendar, to two CurrentDate in different RadScheduleView. How can i do that?

```
<telerik:RadCalendar Name="radCalendar"
    Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="200" 
    Height="320" Width="400"
    SelectedDate="{Binding CurrentDate, ElementName=radScheduleView,  Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionMode="Single" DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDate, Mode=TwoWay}">
</telerik:RadCalendar>
```

I want to have two `ElementName=radScheduleView` and `ElementName=radScheduleView1`

**EDIT**

here's my code that need to be bound

```
<telerik:RadCalendar Name="radCalendar"
     Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="200" 
     Height="320" Width="400"
     SelectionMode="Single" DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDate, Mode=TwoWay}" >

     <telerik:RadCalendar.SelectedDate>
          <MultiBinding Converter="MultiValueConverter" Mode="TwoWay">
              <Binding ElementName="radScheduleView" Path="CurrentDate"/>
              <Binding ElementName="radScheduleView1" Path="CurrentDate"/>
          </MultiBinding>
     </telerik:RadCalendar.SelectedDate>
```

```
<telerik:RadScheduleView Name="radScheduleView1" 
      Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="130" 
      Height="420" Width="570"
      AppointmentsSource="{Binding Appointments}"
      SelectedAppointment="{Binding SelectedAppointment, Mode=TwoWay}"
      ActiveViewDefinitionIndex="{Binding ActiveViewDefinitionIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"
      CurrentDate="{Binding CurrentDate, Mode=TwoWay}">

      <telerik:RadScheduleView.ViewDefinitions>
         <telerik:DayViewDefinition MinorTickLength="10min" />
         </telerik:RadScheduleView.ViewDefinitions>
      </telerik:RadScheduleView>

<telerik:RadScheduleView Name="radScheduleView" 
     Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="130" 
     Height="420" Width="570"
     AppointmentsSource="{Binding Appointments}"
     SelectedAppointment="{Binding SelectedAppointment, Mode=TwoWay}"
     ActiveViewDefinitionIndex="{Binding ActiveViewDefinitionIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"
     CurrentDate="{Binding CurrentDate, Mode=TwoWay}">

     <telerik:RadScheduleView.ViewDefinitions>
          <telerik:DayViewDefinition MinorTickLength="1h" />
      </telerik:RadScheduleView.ViewDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`MultiBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of simple `Binding` and use it with the [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation like the following one:

```
public class MultiValueConverterExtension : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter {
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        return this;
    }
    object IMultiValueConverter.Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return values[1];
    }

    object[] IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return new object[] { value, value };
    }
}
```

In this case XAML will be like this one:

```
<telerik:RadCalendar Name="radCalendar"
    Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="200" 
    Height="320" Width="400"
    SelectionMode="Single" DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDate, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <telerik:RadCalendar.SelectedDate>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiValueConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
             <Binding ElementName="radScheduleView" Path="CurrentDate"/>
             <Binding ElementName="radScheduleView1" Path="CurrentDate"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </telerik:RadCalendar.SelectedDate>
</telerik:RadCalendar>
```

Comment: @Mirza I've modified XAML in my answer to shouw you what I'm talking about

Comment: there is an error `The type 'local:MultiValueConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built` i set local to my namespace

Comment: @Mirza: obviously, you must define converter in resources.

Comment: Defining converter in the resources is not necessary, but this approach should work. This is a markup extension, so setter like Converter="{local:MultiValueConverter}" should be correct. Have you tried rebuilding your project? You can also use converter like <MultiBinding.Converter><local:MultiValueConverterExtension/></MultiBinding.Converter>. I also advise you to check if you declared converter in the correct namespace.

Comment: @Alexis yes its in the correct namespace i put it in code behind, now there's this error `'{local:MultiValueConverter}' value is not a valid MarkupExtension expression. Cannot resolve 'MultiValueConverter' in namespace 'clr-namespace:DSSchedule'. 'MultiValueConverter' must be a subclass of MarkupExtension.`

Comment: Sounds really strange. Can you try to use converter as the resource (like in the Dennis comment) or declare it without using markup extension syntax (<MultiBinding.Converter><local:MultiValueConverterExtension/></MultiBinding.Conv‌​erter>)?

Comment: @Alexis `The tag 'MultiBinding.Converter' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.` i try it without using markup extension syntax

Comment: @Mirza This property should exist (since .net 3.0 according documentation [MultiBinding.Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.converter(v=vs.100).aspx))... can you post your XAML that uses MultiBinding (starting with RadCalendar element)?

Comment: @Alexis i put all my XAML code that need to be bound there, maybe it can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91565/discussion-between-alexis-and-mirza).